# Is storing data in class attribute bad practice?

Tags: python

I need to use some data multiple times in my project. I don't want to read it globally and then pass it to all functions. Is it good practice to store it in class attribute?

Something like this:

```
class SomeData():
    _data = None
    data_path = 'path.csv'

    @classmethod
    def get_data(cls):
        if cls._data is None:
            cls._data = pd.read_csv(cls.data_path)
        return cls._data.copy()
```

I have many data sources and I would like to replicate this pattern. If it is not good idea, what would be the best solution?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Example usage:

```
package/module1.py
def fun1():
    df = SomeData.get_data()
    ...

package/module2.py
def fun2():
    df = SomeData.get_data()
    ...

script.py
from package.module1 import fun1
from package.module2 import fun2

x = fun1()
y = fun2()
```

**Edit2:**

I have found builtin decorators in `functools` package: `cached_property` and `lru_cache` which can be used to cashe expensive operations: [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property).

Comment: could you show us how you're going to use `SomeData` elsewhere?

Comment: @gog Example added

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely fine to load data and store in class variables. I read contents of 4 different files of historical data, totalling 3-4 GB, before running my Algo program.

Only caveat being, I notice some performance delay in program execution with and without loading historical data(3-4GB). With data loaded my program takes an extra 30-50 seconds to complete in backtest.

So I have removed all unnecessary datapoints and stored them as pickled dataframe, to load if needed. Its negligible if you load less data.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the data in a static (class) field, not in an object field.
Since this data is not applicable to any class of this type at any time it is a bad practice.

Instead, create an instance of this object and store the data in the object, this was different instances can access different data.

I recommend you read the basics of object oriented programming principles.

Comment: If I store data in object I will need to pass this object to any function that needs to use this data. So this is not really different from simple reading csv file to variable.

Comment: using global variables is a bad practice too. if your functions need it - pass it! otherwise your code is untestable!

Comment: So you recommend loading raw data in highest level of abstraction and then pass it through all functions to the bottom of the process? I am not really convinced by this solution...

Comment: I would rather say this is global constant since it is not changing during program runtime. This is not very different from reading it from csv, so am not really sure code is untestable..

Comment: There are standard good and bad practices of how to write code, most of which aren't even programming language dependent. Each one has reasons for why it is a good or bad practice. If you want to ignore them, you can. But then why ask?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional python developer, so I won't give my own opinion as to whether or not it's bad practice, but I'm writing this answer to note that the pattern for `datasets` in scikit-learn is very different, and is likely what other people will expect rather than your pattern.

You load a dataset in scikit-learn using an import like the following:

```
from sklearn import datasets
df_iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

The directory structure looks like:

```
sklearn
|-> datasets
    |-> __init__.py
    |-> _base.py
```

... `__init__.py` contains a line to import `load_iris` from `_base.py`, and `_base.py` contains the actual code for `load_iris` to load the dataframe. (If you like, you can just put `load_iris` in `__init__.py` as well.)

See here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/datasets/_base.py

Comment: Using this method I would load all my data during datasets module import and I will end up with global variables in module instead of classes. I am not sure if it is better solution.

Comment: "I would load all my data during datasets module import" ... no you wouldn't; you would just load the function definitions like load_iris. The actual data won't get imported until you call one of those functions.

Comment: Ok, I thought by this: "If you like, you can just put load_iris in __init__.py as well.", you meant to call load_iris function in __init__.py. Anyway with this solution every time I need iris_data I need to load it and this is what I want to avoid (loading big files few times).

Comment: "every time I need iris_data I need to load it" -> I don't think so. Your version of load_iris could have the same null check that you have given in your sample code. But you're right -- you would have a global variable floating around in the module. I don't see the problem in this, because it's actually more like a global constant. Anyway, to answer your question again, I'm not sure if your idea is considered good practice, and I'm following this page with interest :-)